# Using different data in the same donut chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts

I'm trying to create a donut chart that displays `inactiveStaff` vs `activeStaff`, based on `totalStaff`.

Here's an example of the data I'm using

```
var salesPeople = [
  { "region": "West",
    "toursCreated": 644,
    "totalStaff": 644,
    "activeStaff": 399,
    "inactiveStaff": 245
  }
];
```

I want to calculate the percentages of the `activeStaff` and `inactiveStaff` and display them within the donut chart.

I'm not sure how I can bind this kind of data to the pie variable, and then display it within the actual SVG I create.
ie.

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.salesPeople; });
```

I am familiar with building pie charts from one set of data, like the population of different countries — but I can't figure out how to create a pie chart from one object of data like this and show the `activeStaff` vs `inactiveStaff` in the same donut chart.

Here's a [fiddle](http://codepen.io/mcKrack/pen/QNoRYy?editors=0010) that creates a simple example of a donut chart that uses the kind of data i'm used to, and below it is the data I want to use but commented out — hopefully it makes it easier to understand what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Hi Krang. Is it a donut chart or a pie chart that you are trying to create?

Comment: @Joe, a donut chart — but either can illustrate what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your problem, you can do this:

```
var inactive = {"name": "inactive"};
inactive.population = salesPeople[0].inactiveStaff;

var active = {"name": "active"};
active.population = salesPeople[0].activeStaff;

var myArray = [];
myArray.push(inactive);
myArray.push(active);

render(myArray);
```

Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKbXod?editors=0010

Comment: — thanks! this does work, i'm wondering if there is a better way to handle this data though, perhaps somewhere else in the code?

Comment: Can you tell me more?